# UIView.superView (BOOL) == Fail

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, casting, boolean

I have a simple method that checks for the superview of a view, and returns a BOOL.  However, intermittently the method fails to produce the right answer (or at least the answer Iʻm expecting).

The method is:

```
-(BOOL) isTheViewShowing
{
    return (BOOL) [theView superview];
}
```

There is a Tap Gesture that removes the view, and I logged the following (when the undesirable happens):

```
isTheViewShowing: NO
theView: <UIView: 0x3c1a10; frame = (0 232; 320 135); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x365480>>,
superView: <UIView: 0x392400; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x35fe90>>
```

As the log shows the superView exists, but why is the cast failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> superView: <UIView: 0x392400

Note that the low order byte of `superview` is 0x00. I haven't really looked into what happens when you try to cast a pointer to a `BOOL`, but since a `BOOL` is essentially a `char` I wouldn't be at all surprised if the compiler just looks at the low order byte. Try this instead:

```
-(BOOL) isTheViewShowing
{
    return ([theView superview] != nil);
}
```

That's better on two counts: 1) it actually works, and 2) it better communicates what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 good pickup on the address lower order byte.  could explain why the problem is intermittent.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, just outta curiosity, would the casting of a large int to bool fail under similar circumstances (cause the pointer itself is just an int, right?)

Comment: @TMacGyver Yes, the same thing could happen. I wouldn't go so far as to equate a pointer with an int, though -- they're different types.

Comment: @Caleb what about the simple truth test of a pointer if(someObject) - I've never had that fail on me but have often wondered if it's vulnerable to this issue. Would you be able to briefly comment on that? If you feel it's outside the scope of this comment thread just let me know and maybe I'll post a question. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlVeazey No, there's no problem there. The OP was trying to explicitly `cast` a pointer to a `BOOL`, but the expression in an `if` can be a pointer (i.e. there's no casting going on). I still prefer `if (foo != nil)...` for clarity, but some people consider that redundant and prefer `if (foo) ...`. Either one works.